# A question on the elements of a group centre and actions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group whose centre $Z(G)$ contains the element $g$. Show that ${\displaystyle {\hat {g}}}$, the action to the permutation group is the identity permutation.

I get that by definition ${\displaystyle {\hat {g}}} = {\displaystyle {\hat {k}}} {\displaystyle {\hat {g}}}{\displaystyle {\hat {k}}}^{-1}$ for $k$ in $G$ but I do not know how to move on.

Comment: Could you include the definition of $\hat{g}$ for $g\in G$?

Comment: That is the action (bijective homomorphism) from the group to the symmetric group.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the definition to it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the notation $\sigma$, i.e., $\sigma=\phi(g)=\hat{g}$, which you have defined.
Then we have
$$
\sigma(k)=gkg^{-1}=kgg^{-1}=k,
$$
because $g$ is in the center of $G$. Hence $\sigma(k)$ is the identity.